# Oracle stored procedure never returns to calling desktop app

Tags: java, oracle, swing, stored-procedures

I'm working on the following (inherited) system:  we have a Java Swing desktop application (Java 1.6) that calls a sproc (Oracle 10g database), sproc does a lot of work, and when the sproc is done, the app logs a bit of information about the call from the output parameters, and that's it.

However, around the time we moved these machines to a new data center (the desktop for the app and the server for the database), the application begins performing like this:  applications calls sproc, sproc does its work, sproc logs all the way up to the very end (last statement is a log statement), and then never returns to the application, which sits there presumably eternally (we've waited ~3 days when the whole process typically takes 3-5 hours).

We've combed logs in the app and the sproc for error messages, but none seem to be getting thrown, logged, or as far as we can tell, swallowed.

We also noticed that certain parts of the code stopped committing as they did previously - from looking at the code, I'm not sure how it ever worked.  However, we added a commit to the very end and now everything seems to be committing properly, but the app still 'hangs' and never returns to the desktop app.

The sproc being called is very complex and has a lot of very messy code in there - I wouldn't be at all surprised if this issue was somehow exposed by the data center migration.

What else could be possibly be preventing a sproc from returning like this?

Comment: My guess is that the new data center has a (new) firewall that is killing the connection between the application and the database after a period of inactivity.  When the procedure finishes, it tries to send a message back to the client at which point Oracle finds out that the connection doesn't exist.  Meanwhile, the client is waiting for a reply that will never come.  I'd look at firewall settings first.  But you may be able to enable dead connection detection to force some traffic to prevent the firewall from considering the connection idle.

Comment: That is a possibility - there's a way to kick off the sproc where it handles much less data and returns in as little as 5-10 minutes, and it works perfectly then.

Comment: Do you have source code of the procedure?

Comment: If you mean 'do I have access to the source' - yes, we have access to all the source code.  Can't post any here, though.  It basically contains many thousands of lines of somewhat complicated business logic.